# Ubuntu 12.10 installation not initializing while trying to install from USB

Tags: usb

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.10, i used Livelinux sotware to install it from USB, after creating the USB key i reboot by pc, i got the Ubuntu desktop screen and a window asking me either to try the OS or install, i choose install followed the onscreen instruction, i oped to install Ubuntu within Windows 7 option and clicked continue, but when the system restarts, i am getting the same screen asking me whether to try Ubuntu or install it. can someone help me out with that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your computer is still trying to boot from the USB. Try to take it out of the computer and boot again.

Comment: The OS is not installing, Ubuntu is loading from the CD but it is not installing. Even when i select install option, i am only getting the Ubuntu desktop from Live CD.

Comment: Huh, might want to make that a bit clearer =) You say that you are rebooting, but when is this happening? If you got to choose to install alongside Windows, then the installer must have begun? When does it fail?

Comment: Yes i chose install along side windows 7 option and click restart to continue option, but the installer is not starting, i am getting the same desktop screen that i got before. can u please help me out?

Comment: Okey, okey. I think I understand. Install within Windows means to use WUBI. Which means you start windows, and use the USB to create a virtual machine inside windows. If you want dualboot, to choose between Ubuntu and Windows at startup, you need to choose Install alongside Windows (or something along those lines).

Comment: I also trying same, event i tried 11.10 as well..i boot device using pen-drive..installation screen come (try or want to install)..it goes for some next level also..but automatic it shutdown...pls suggest here if any one have any idea about it.